# Custom URL scheme with Google Chrome in Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, url-scheme

I'm developing an app and I need to open a url scheme when I want. I mean:

We have two mobiles, the sender and the receiver. The receiver is waiting that the sender sends a variable of a url scheme. When the receiver gets that variable, It adds it to the url scheme and then try to open (redirect) to another native app (url scheme).

It works great in the native internet browser installed by default in Android, but there are some mobiles that only have Google Chrome.

So the main problem is that I cannot open a url scheme when I want (from another mobile or with a timeout) with Google Chrome in Android.

One of the codes I've tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                setTimeout(function() {              
                    window.location = "twitter://";
                }, 500);
            };
        </script>
        <iframe id="l" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance and hope to find a solution!

Comment: Mobile browsers LOVE to block certain actions until a user has interacted with the page. This may be the case with url redirects. Also, what happens when you try to open the link? Errors? Have you tried assigning href to an anchor tag and tapping it manually?

Comment: Hi, It tries to redirect it, but nothing happens. Just like if the Chrome refreshes the page. We have tried a lot of things but any works. We need to have a time out checking if it can receive the parameter or not yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually Google did deprecate that function since [Google Chrome version 25](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

Other way to do it you can use Android Intents like this :

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

and then set the manifest like this

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="zxing" android:host="scan" android:path="/"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean to put this in the app itself or in the web (Chrome) that opens the url scheme?
I need to open an app with some parameters from a web. And those parameters are sended from another web and connected to a MySQL database. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @DaniG. how you solved it? I mean from web browser, without using native app